# 405 (Method Not Allowed) with notion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notion

I am working on a small project in which data after filling the form will be posted on the notion.

Error while submitting button from form:contact.jsx?287f:14          POST http://localhost:3000/contact 405 (Method Not Allowed)[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFoRn.jpg)

source:-
[notion db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKfBD.jpg)

here were ui renders
contact.jsx::-
'''

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ContactCode from '../components/ContactCode';
import styles from '../styles/ContactPage.module.css';

const ContactPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');  

  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/contact`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        name: name,
        email: email,
        subject:subject,
         message: message 
        }),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      alert('Your response has been received!');
      setName('');
      setEmail('');
      setSubject('');
      setMessage('');
    } else {
      alert('There was an error. Please try again in a while.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div>
        <h3 className={styles.heading}>Reach Out Via Socials</h3>
        <ContactCode />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 className={styles.heading}>Or Fill Out This Form</h3>
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={submitForm}>
          <div className={styles.flex}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">Subject</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="subject"
              id="subject"
              value={subject}
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            <textarea
              name="message"
              id="message"
              rows="5"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: { title: 'Contact' },
  };
}

export default ContactPage;
```

'''

api/contact.js :-

```
const { Client } = require('@notionhq/client');

const notion = new Client({
  auth: 'secret_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ msg: 'Only POST requests are allowed' });
  }
  try {
    const { name, email, subject, message } = JSON.parse(req.body);
    await notion.pages.create({
      parent: {
        database_id: 'https://www.notion.so/62xxxxx713xx`,
      },
      properties: {
        Name: {
          title: [
            {
              text: {
                content: name,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        Email: {
          email,
        },
        Subject: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: subject,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        Message: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: message,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
    res.status(201).json({ msg: 'Success' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Failed' });
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.method` in the api when it throws that error?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/contact

Answer (score 0):

here were ui renders contact.jsx::- ''' update your method name 'post' small case to 'POST' uppercase

example:

```
   const submitForm = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
   const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/contact`, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
      name: name,
      email: email,
      subject:subject,
     message: message 
     }),
   });
```

because in your api/contact.js :-
you are strictly checking for uppercase 'POST' string name

```
export default async (req, res) => {
if (req.method !== 'POST') {
   return res.status(405).json({ msg: 'Only POST requests are allowed' });
 }
```

suggestion:
always use built-in constants for custom constants for enums checks

Comment: ya, I updated it a as but still showing method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

still not working

my updated code:-
contact.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ContactCode from '../components/ContactCode';
import styles from '../styles/ContactPage.module.css';

const ContactPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');  

  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/contact', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        name: name,
        email: email,
        subject:subject,
         message: message 
        }),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      alert('Your response has been received!');
      setName('');
      setEmail('');
      setSubject('');
      setMessage('');
    } else {
      alert('There was an error. Please try again in a while.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div>
        <h3 className={styles.heading}>Reach Out Via Socials</h3>
        <ContactCode />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 className={styles.heading}>Or Fill Out This Form</h3>
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={submitForm}>
          <div className={styles.flex}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">Subject</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="subject"
              id="subject"
              value={subject}
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            <textarea
              name="message"
              id="message"
              rows="5"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: { title: 'Contact' },
  };
}

export default ContactPage;
```

contact.js:-

```
const { Client } = require('@notionhq/client');

const notion = new Client({
  auth: 'secret_xyAk81xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ msg: 'Only POST requests are allowed' });
  }
  try {
    const { name, email, subject, message } = JSON.parse(req.body);
    await notion.pages.create({
      parent: {
        database_id: 'cba7f642ede143xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      },
      properties: {
        Name: {
          title: [
            {
              text: {
                content: name,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        Email: {
          email,
        },
        Subject: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: subject,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        Message: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: message,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
    res.status(201).json({ msg: 'Success' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Failed' });
  }
```

error
[from fetch!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C3x6.jpg)